# Reusing a process' mailbox in Erlang

Tags: erlang

If an Erlang process `proc1` is killed (`exit(killed)`) and another process `proc2` is notified of this event because it's linked to the process `proc1`, is there a possibility to respawn a replacement process with the mailbox of the killed process `proc1`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not really. Processes don't share any data, so when one dies no other can access any of it's memory.  Erlang would not know how long to wait to garbage-collect such mailbox.

You could simulate that with separate proxy process that just keeps track of mailbox.

Or you could try to handle little better being killed in `proc1`. You could use `process_flag(trap_exit, true)` which would allow you to receive `exit(killed)` message as normal message `{'EXIT',FromPid,killed}`.  And when you receive you read you whole mailbox, and then continue exiting with all messages being part of exit reason.

It could look somewhat like this:

```
init(Args) ->
   process_flag(trap_exit, true),
   .... % continiue process innicializaiton.

loop(State) ->
  receive 
   .... 
    {'EXIT', _FromPid, killed} ->
        exit({killed, all_messages()})
  end.


all_messages() ->
   all_messages([]).

all_messages(Messages) ->
     receive 
        AnyMessage ->
            all_messages( [AnyMessage|Messages])
     after 0 ->
            lists:reverse(Messages)
     end.
```

And `proc2` would receive all unprocessed messages, and could send them again to newly spawn process.

Comment: This is a mistake, you should change `lists:rever(Messages)` to `lists:reverse(Messages)`.